# Vimscript: How can I implement interactive method argument autocompletion?

Tags: vim

I am writing a plugin for vim in which I am calling a ruby script.

The script finds the arguments for the method and I have managed to display them in the popup using `completefunc`. Here is how it looks.

[image: Image of popup window]

This is great but if I chose one of the options the popup closes and I lose the rest. Is there a way that I can keep the popup open and use it to paste things in while typing? I do feel like I am misusing the popup as it seems to be designed for single word auto-completion. If that is the case could someone suggest an elegant alternative approach?

Best,

Dionysis

Comment: +1, sometimes I also miss such kind of function when I use latex-box. Now I just echomsg the candidates in the menu, and use :message to show them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way around closing the popup menu after a candidate has been selected and inserted into the buffer. However, nothing prevents you from automatically re-triggering the same completion (using `feedkeys()` and the `CursorMovedI` event), provided the conditions for continued completion are given.

The [AutoComplPop - Automatically opens popup menu](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) plugin does this; you can check its implementation for details.

Comment: Hmm.. I went into `feedkeys` and `CursorMovedI` but I decided to follow your idea of re-triggering but after the user types a comma which would be what would separate the arguments. I then remove the mapping when the user inserts a closing parenthesis or `<esc>` `<C-c>`'s to normal mode. It does feel a bit hacky though and I am wondering if I m going to have any problems with that approach.  *`inoremap , ,<space><C-x><C-o>` *`inoremap ) <esc>:iunmap ,<CR>:iunmap )<CR>i<right>)` *`inoremap <esc> <esc>:iunmap ,\|iunmap )\|iunmap <C-c>` *`inoremap <C-c> <esc>:iunmap ,\|iunmap )\|iunmap <C-c>`

Comment: @Dionysis That looks fine to me; with your special needs, there's no straightforward solution in Vim!